# Get the image size (height and width) in excel files instead of the original size when using Apache POI (for both xls and xlsx files)

Tags: java, html, excel, image, apache-poi

Currently we're developing an api to convert xls and xlsx files to html, we want to keep the images (both the size and position in excel files) We want to get the size of the images exactly what we see in the excel files (after being resized). We tried this approach:

```
    for (HSSFPictureData pic : workbook.getAllPictures()) {
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(pic.getData());
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
    System.out.println(image.getWidth() + ":" + image.getHeight());
}
```

But it returned the original size, not the one we resized in the excel file. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I changed the poi version from 4.1.2 to 5.0.0 as you recommended and it worked! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Workbook.getAllPictures()` gets all picture files  embedded in `Excel` file. Those picture files contain the plain picture data. So there cannot be any method to get the scaled picture size.

The scaled pictures are contained in sheet drawings and are anchored to sheet's cells. So to get the scaled pictures, one needs traversing the sheet drawings to get the `Picture`s out of them. From `Picture` one can get the anchored position in sheet, the dimension of the anchor (aka scaled size) and also the `PictureData`.

Complete example (tested and works using current `apache poi 5.0.0`, works for both `HSSF` as well as `XSSF`).

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFPatriarch;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.ImageUtils;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.util.List;

class ExcelGetPicturesWithPositionAndSize {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  //Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelWithImages.xlsx"));
  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelWithImages.xls"));

  for (Sheet sheet : workbook) {
   String sheetname = sheet.getSheetName();

   Drawing drawing = sheet.getDrawingPatriarch();
   
   List<?> shapes = null;
   if (drawing instanceof XSSFDrawing) {
    shapes = ((XSSFDrawing)drawing).getShapes();
   } else if (drawing instanceof HSSFPatriarch) {
    shapes = ((HSSFPatriarch)drawing).getChildren();
   }
   
   for (Object shape : shapes) {
    if (shape instanceof Picture) {
     Picture picture = (Picture)shape;
     
     String shapename = picture.getShapeName();
     int row = picture.getClientAnchor().getRow1();
     int col = picture.getClientAnchor().getCol1();
System.out.println(
 "Picture with Shapename: " + shapename + 
 " is located sheet: " + sheetname + 
 ", row: " + row + 
 ", col: " + col
 );

     Dimension dimension = ImageUtils.getDimensionFromAnchor(picture);
System.out.println(
 "Picture's size in EMU: width=" + dimension.getWidth() + ", height=" + dimension.getHeight() +
 ", in pixel: width=" + dimension.getWidth()/Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL + ", height=" + dimension.getHeight()/Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL
 ); 
 
     PictureData pictureData =  picture.getPictureData();
System.out.println(
 "Picture's data: bytes=" + pictureData.getData().length +
 ", mime type=" + pictureData.getMimeType() +
 ", suggested file extension=" + pictureData.suggestFileExtension()
 ); 

    }
   } 
  }

  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Seems like it will take the size according to the cell.  I can see if I place the image (width: 100px, height: 500 px) to a cell containing a lot of text, with width = 1000 px, the width will be 1000 px instead of 100 px when I follow this approach

Comment: @thang dang: Sorry, cannot reproduce the issue. It works for me independent of different cell sizes.

Comment: I changed the poi version from 4.1.2 to 5.0.0 as you recommended and it worked! thank you!